# Cómo hacer que Switch me valide condiciones sobre una cadena de texto?

Tags: c#, unity

Estoy haciendo un chatbot y  tengo el siguiente problema. `switch` es muy estricto en mi código, si cambia una mayúscula o minúscula o se ponen acentos ya no detecta la frase. Me gustaría poner, si contiene una de las estas palabras es igual a "x", o si contiene esta frase aunque se pongan signos de exclamación, etc. que la detecte, es posible?

Es para Unity con C#. Gracias de antemano!

```
public InputField campoTexto;
    private string UserDialogo;
    private bool enviartexto = false;

    public Text MascotaDialogo;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
            if (enviartexto == true)
        {
            switch (campoTexto.text)
            {
                case "Hola bot":
                case "Hola":
                    Debug.Log("" + UserDialogo);
                    MascotaDialogo.text = "Hola amigo!";
                    enviartexto = false;
                    break;
                case "como estas":
                case "como te encuentras":
                    Debug.Log("" + UserDialogo);
                    MascotaDialogo.text = "Estoy bien! y tu?";
                    enviartexto = false;
                    break;
                case "bien":
                case "muy bien":
                    Debug.Log("" + UserDialogo);
                    MascotaDialogo.text = "Me alegro!";
                    enviartexto = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    Debug.Log("No command Detected");
                    enviartexto = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    public void OnSubmit()
    {
        UserDialogo = campoTexto.text;
        enviartexto = true;
    }
```

Comment: No, no puedes hacer lo que quieres con un `switch`. De todas maneras, tampoco es la mejor manera de hacer lo que intentas. Probablemente un diccionario sean una estructura mucho mas apropiada para asignar una respuesta dependiendo de la entrada proporcionada

Comment: Gracias por la corrección @Pikoh lo buscaré, soy novato en programación estoy aprendiendo a la fuerza según necesidades para hacer juegos entonces hay cosas complejas que sé hacer y cosas fáciles que no tengo ni idea. Gracias por contestar.

Comment: Siempre es bueno fijarse en lo que ya está hecho, sobre todo si no tienes experiencia. Fíjate por ejemplo en [este enlace](https://github.com/qxsch/ChatBot), estudia ese código y luego trata de replicarlo en tu aplicación. Suerte

Comment: Ah,y lo olvidaba. Bienvenido a [es.so]!!! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta

Comment: Podrías hacer un if(campoTexto.contains("loquesea")) combinado con un toUpperCase para evitar el tema de las mayúsculas y podrías quitar las tildes con un replace para evitar eso también

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano si claro. El problema es que si tiene 20 preguntas/respuestas, debe hacer 20 if's. Para dos o tres, es posible. Para mas, se convierte en un monstruo inmanejable :)

Comment: Igual me equivoco pero serían los mismos casos que con el switch, ahí no habría diferencia

Comment: Claro. Eso es lo que le comento al OP en mi primer comentario, que ni switch ni if, que a nada que tengas mas de 4-5 opciones el codigo empieza a ser inmanejable.

Comment: Muy cierto @Pikoh =)

Comment: Lo más simple que se me ocurre para mejorarlo es aplicar un `.ToLower()` en el switch; `switch(campoTexto.text.ToLower())` y todos los cases en minúsculas, de ese modo, al menos te olvidas de las mayúsculas y minúsculas

Comment: En realidad como dice @Pikoh por alla arriba, esto no se hace asi. si lo queres hacer de prueba, genial. Pero esto se hace con dicccionarios y arboles invertidos. En realidad, la pregunta no tiene respuesta como esta, salvo que quieras una solucion solo para estos casos.

Comment: Gracias a todos por vuestras sugerencias!! al final voy a implementar un chatbot de google, quería evitar esto y hacer el mio propio pero esta claro que con mi nivel de programación va a ser que por el momento imposible. Gracias!!!